# Editing tech stack "About Our Tech Stack" doesn't really save

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I had a small capitalization issue on our edit tech stack as shown:

[image]

I fixed it and clicked save and it looks to be saved..I even clicked the button `Save & Publish`.  But when I click back to the tech stack it shows up again as "microsoft" rather than "Microsoft".

The console in chrome shows the following errors:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I just went to fix this but [Arie](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/504912/arie-litovsky) beat me to it. Thanks Arie :)